Is a Taproot output with unparseable x-only pubkey unspendable?
The first output of f33ead0ef49900a782b83eede071f9b5f12142d2a403092452fd6ecf99f153c8 can't be parsed with secp256k1_xonly_pubkey_parse. [0]
Does that mean there's no way to spend it? I.e. there's no possible key or script path.
BIP341 says:

A Taproot output is a native SegWit output (see BIP141) with version number 1, and a 32-byte witness program.

Typically this witness program is a public key, sometimes a NUMS point with no corresponding private key. But it seems it can also be a coordinate off the curve, e.g. x > 2^256 - 232 - 29 - 28 - 27 - 26 - 24 - 1.
[0] as discovered here: https://github.com/josibake/bitcoin/discussions/4#discussioncomment-10348541


Does that mean there's no way to spend it? I.e. there's no possible key or script path.

Correct.
It cannot be spent as a key path, because that would require a valid signature for the output point interpreted as a public key (which will fail even before getting to the signature validation part).
And it cannot be spent through a script path, because that requires providing an internal key which, when tweaked, yields the output point. Since the output point is not on the curve in this situation, the result of the tweaking can never be equal to it.

Indeed it's a witness program. I meant to point out that people interpret this program as an x-only public key, but that's not always the case. I edited the question to add the word "program".

Right; most script-related consensus rules only care about outputs at spending time. E.g. bare scriptPubKey keys can contain unknown opcodes, be too large, contain unbalanced OP_IF OP_ENDIFs, contain pushes that straddle the script boundary... all of these rules only apply when the output is attempted to be spent. At creation time, they're just byte arrays.
